# Highlight a row that aiming cursor in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, cursor, highlight, jtextpane

How to highlight a row text in current cursor position without clicking when I am aiming my cursor in my text in `JTextPane`?

Here my example :

[image: example]

So, if my cursor aiming (no click) in line 10, then it will highlight all word in line 10.

here my problem :

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        int x=e.getX();
        int y=e.getY();
        component.requestFocus();

        Document doc = component.getDocument();
        Element root = doc.getDefaultRootElement();
        Element element = root.getElement(e.getX());
        int start = element.getStartOffset();
        int sel = start + e.getY();
        component.select(sel, sel);
}
```

Comment: Is your question: How do I implement it? I have downclicked your question because it isn't clear what you want. Please improve and I will remove the downclick, okay?

Comment: yes, i want impement it.

Comment: Okay thanks. Please eit/improve the actual question text

Comment: My post has been update

Comment: is my question still less? i think it is enough.

Comment: @newbie `i think it is enough`, no, it isn't. What have you tried to solve it on your own? Please post a [mcve] that shows your effort :)

Comment: Explain your question with more details, use Google translate if needed, I'm confused on what you're asking. Add an image or ASCII art if needed so we can understand what you want.

Comment: my post has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Line Painter](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/line-painter/). It shows how to highlight the background of the line based on the current caret position.

Since you want the line of the mouse position you will obviously need to modify the code to handle the `mouseMoved(...)` event of a `MouseListener`.

So you will need to use the information in the `MouseEvent` to get the `Point` where the mouse is currently located. You would then need to create a `Rectangle` using this point. I would guess you just need to make the width/height have a value of 1 for the Rectangle.

Comment: how to if without click?

Comment: @newbie, I already told you how to do it. You need to modify the code in the link. We are not here to write the code for you.